# Prove that if $f(x)$ is differentiable, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, then $\int_0^1|f(x)-f'(x)|\mathrm dx\geq\frac1{\mathrm e}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, then $\int_0^1|f(x)-f'(x)|\mathrm dx\geq\frac1{\mathrm e}$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $$F(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$$
We have
$$\frac{1}{e}=F(1)-F(0)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}F^{\prime}(x)dx\leqslant\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\left|F^{\prime}(x)\right|dx\leqslant\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\left|f(x)-f^{\prime}(x)\right|dx$$